# jquery scale with origin middle and center come back to original position after scale complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i'm trying to scale element with and jquery-ui-1.8.21

```
$("#star1").effect("scale", {
    percent: 125,
    origin: ['middle', 'center']
}, 1000);
```

but after the scale complete, the element jump to original top left

like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ncqps/

i've googled it and found that this was known bug in http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4316 , i've also try the workaround that suggested there, but still not working

someone knows how to fix it   ?

thx

Comment: no one knows about this?

Comment: At this time, this bug has not been corrected yet. this script : [http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html "jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale")
runs fine for scaling correctly from the **center** of an object